# Order seaborn countplot by Month

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

this should be very simple but I'm trying to order a seaborn countplot by Month.
The default is in reverse order (latest months first), so I would like to either simply reverse the order or specify the order - ideally I'd like to understand how to do both.

This is the code I have:

`sns.countplot(data = cycling ,x = cycling['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m') ) plt.xticks(rotation=45) plt.show()`

I tried adding `order = cycling['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')` but it just splits the bars further based on how many entries I had for that month. So it goes from this: [Barplot image 1: wrong order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLKdr.png)

To this: [Barplot image 2: wrong order + sliced too much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXaJ5.png)

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: did you check the output of: `order = cycling['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`?
As you are running it on the original dataframe and not on the groups, you likely have a lot of repetitions in there:
`order = ['2022-01','2022-01',...,'2023-01']`
instead of:
`order = ['2022-01','2022-02',...,'2023-01']`

Comment: You're right, I get a lot of repetitions. I tried ordering using a groupby but didn't seem to work, perhaps because I made a mistake.

Comment: see the answer below. the use of `set` will remove duplicates from the list and the use of `list` will convert the type back to list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `order = list(set(order))` to remove duplicates from your list.

the use of `set` will remove duplicates from the list and the use of `list` will convert the type back to list

you can also reverse the auto-generated `order` list: by using `order.reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

By default, the order of appearance in the 'Date' column is used.  If your dataframe is strictly from newest to oldest, you could just invert the dataframe.  If there isn't a strict order, you can sort the dataframe.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cycling = pd.DataFrame({'Date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('20210801', '20230123', freq='D'), 500)})
ax = sns.countplot(x=cycling.sort_values('Date')['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot ordered by date]